# Python 3 - Merging an .xls / deleting rows / removing duplicates

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am attempting to combine 3  .xls files - and want to do this in python3.

I need to delete the some rows first then combine them into one .xls , then remove duplicates.(i will later manipulate the data for graphs)

I seek guidance on which modules to use that work in python3 that can achieve this effect.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I seek guidance on which modules to use that work in python3 that can achieve this effect.

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is definitely your best bet.

> 03 - Lesson: - Creating functions - Reading from EXCEL - Exporting to EXCEL - slice and dice data
>
> 04 - Lesson: - Adding/deleting columns - Index operations

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Here's how to merge the separate files into one sheet:
[Import multiple excel files into python pandas and concatenate them into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat)

Here's how to delete rows: [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Here's how to delete duplicates: [Remove rows with duplicate indices (Pandas DataFrame and TimeSeries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-rows-with-duplicate-indices-pandas-dataframe-and-timeseries)

Comment: Thats ideal, after a few hours installing it (compile errors <Sigh>) got exactly what i needed. Cheers for the swift response.