# Python basic – one line include a list, ‘for’ and ‘if’

Tags: python

it’s a Python newbie question (thanks to the post [Import multiple excel files into python pandas and concatenate them into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat))

The script is:

```
import os

files = os.listdir('C:\\TEST')
files_pdf = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'pdf']
print files_pdf
```

it give all the names of PDF files in the folder.

I am trying to understand it from a basic way. I guess the longest line above functions as:

```
files_ pdf = []
for f in files:
    if f[-3:] == ‘pdf’:
        files_ pdf.append(f)
```

the question is that, what's the difference? and what’s the reason or principle of the ‘f for f in files’?

```
[for f in files if f[-3:] == 'pdf']   #doesn't work
[f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'pdf'] #works
```

thanks.

Comment: thanks, Vaughn Cato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **List Comprehensions**

for example,

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squares = [x**2 for x in nums]
# squares: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

The first part (before `for`) is what will be push into the new list.

So

```
[f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'pdf']
```

just means "use all `f in files` such that `f[-3:] == 'pdf'` to form a list"

There are some really useful trick about list comprehensions.
for example, if you want to create a list contain some empty list for later use,
you can write

```
multi_list = [[] for i in range(10)]   # correct
multi_list = [[]]*10                   # wrong!
```

this is because `[[]]*10` will use the same reference of one list,
but `[[] for i in range(10)]` will create 10 independent list instead.

for more information, you should check [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: LeoMao, this is great! Thanks so much for the guidance and expiations in detail.