# How to add a date from filename to a time column to make datetime column? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have multiple files that are named like this
`2018-08-31-logfile-device1 
2018-09-01-logfile-device1`

in these files the data is sorted this way:
`00:00:00.283672analogue values:[2511, 2383, 2461, 2472]
00:00:00.546165analogue values:[2501, 2395, 2467, 2465]`

I append all these files into one big dataframe with this code: (i got from here: [Import multiple excel files into python pandas and concatenate them into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat))

```
file_log = os.listdir(path)
file_log = [file_log for file_log in glob.glob('*device1*')]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file_log in file_log:
    data = pd.read_csv(file_log,sep='analogue values:',names=['time', 
'col'], engine='python')
    df = data.append(data1)
```

I transform the data and then it looks like this:
`analog1 analog2 analog3 analog4      time
2511    2383    2461    2472  00:00:00.283672
2501    2395    2467    2465  00:00:00.546165
2501    2395    2467    2465  00:00:00.807846
2497    2381    2461    2467  00:00:01.070540
2485    2391    2458    2475  00:00:01.332163`

but the problem is, I want the time column to be date time, where the date is the date from the filename it came from.

`analog1 analog2 analog3 analog4      datetime
2511    2383    2461    2472       2018-08-31 00:00:00.283672
2501    2395    2467    2465       2018-08-31 00:00:00.546165
2501    2395    2467    2465       2018-08-31 00:00:00.807846
2497    2381    2461    2467       2018-08-31 00:00:01.070540
2485    2391    2458    2475       2018-08-31 00:00:01.332163`

Comment: What is your code for created big DataFrame? Can you add it to question?

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert first 10 values from filename by `file[:10]` to datetime and add to column `time` converted by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

Then `append` each DataFrame to list and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
dfs = []
for file in glob.glob('*device1*'):
    data = pd.read_csv(file,sep='analogue values:',names=['time','col'], engine='python')
    data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(file[:10]) + pd.to_timedelta(data['time'])
    data = data.drop('time', axis=1)
    dfs.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Yes! thanks alot
     i tried a similar thing myself with the data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(file[:10]) + pd.to_timedelta(data['time'])

but it didnt do it the way i wanted it to.