# change date format from filename and join into hourly data in multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiple of csv files whose name indicate date like

```
"cd191108.csv", "cd191120.csv"
```

And csv files contains data like this way:

```
GMT + TZ;Value
10:43:00;10
10:45:00;20
...
```

What I want to do is merge all csv files into one dataframe in pandas but with 'time' columns indicating date from filename and hour from contents of a file like

```
Time;value
2019-11-08 10:43:00;10
```

I made it through like the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

files_csvf = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'csv']
files_csv

dfs=[]
for f in files_csv:
    data = pd.read_csv(f,sep=";",index_col=False)
    data['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(f[2:8])+pd.to_timedelta(data['GMT + TZ'])
    data=data.drop('GMT + TZ',axis=1)
    dfs.append(data)
df=pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
df
```

(refered to [How to add a date from filename to a time column to make datetime column? Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969523/how-to-add-a-date-from-filename-to-a-time-column-to-make-datetime-column-python))

However, the result of 'Time' columns is following:

```
2008-11-19 10:43:00
```

instead of what I expected

```
2019-11-08 10:43:00
```

I tried with "to_datetime" to correct but, it does not work..

```
df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time']
```

Comment: pass `yearfirst=True) so  `df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], yearfirst=True)`

Comment: Thanks, David! I've also realized df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%y%m%d') work as well! So happy to solve my first job ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first line of your date is `2008-11-19 10:43:00` instead but you expected `2019-11-08 10:43:00` then it apparently wrongly ate an extra row as header, so try tweaking:

```
pd.read_csv(..., header=[0])`
```

to make it not eat the first/second row.

Note that's the list `[0]` not the number `0`.