# How to Combine All Excel Files In A Folder Into One Workbook irrespective of headers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I just want to copy the all avaible excel files and paste in one excel sheet. I dont want to find by header(since it is already avaialbe in power query) Just copy paste/consolidet all the data available. here's my code.

```
import xlwings as xw  # pip install xlwings

SOURCE_DIR = 'Files'

excel_files = list(Path(SOURCE_DIR).glob('*.xlsx'))
combined_wb = xw.Book()
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M', t)

for excel_file in excel_files:
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
    for sheet in wb.sheets:
        sheet.copy(after=combined_wb.sheets[0])
    wb.close()

combined_wb.sheets[0].delete()
combined_wb.save('output.xlsx')
if len(combined_wb.app.books) == 1:
    combined_wb.app.quit()
else:
    combined_wb.close()
```

Comment: What is the specific issue with your code?

Comment: it opens excel file but no data saved in output

Comment: Make sure you look for the file in the right directory. It will [should] be in the same directory that the python file is run, not **'SOURCE_DIR'**. If your not sure you can put the full path and file name in **combined_wb.save()** so it saves where you want it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to copy Excel worksheet from multiple Excel files to one Excel file that contains all the worksheets from other Excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67778710/python-how-to-copy-excel-worksheet-from-multiple-excel-files-to-one-excel-file)