# Read all the sheets of a large multiple excel files from a folder and append them into a single dataframe

Tags: python

How can I read multiple large excel files from a folder which is of 1.98 gb, and read all sheets of each and every file and append them into one dataframe.
I am new at python and
I have tried something like below but it takes more than half an hour -

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record = True):
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    for file_name in os.listdir(file_path):
        if '~$' in file_name:
            continue
        else:
            xls = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.join(file_path,file_name))
            for sheets in xls.sheet_names:
                df = df.append(xls.parse(sheets))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to execute code for so long time, because Python is single threaded programming language. This is why I wouldn't recommend you doing (if u decided to make it) in multiple threads because you can encounter OOM error or loose some info during merging them at one time.

To combine each sheet into one dataframe there is already an answer here - [python efficient way to append all worksheets in multiple excel into pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700544/python-efficient-way-to-append-all-worksheets-in-multiple-excel-into-pandas-data)

Here is a short summary which might help you

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in source_dataset_list:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    cdf = pd.concat(df.values())
    out_df = out_df.append(cdf,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, does chunksize help to reduce time?

Comment: @Zeren It might work a bit longer, but this is something you should try by urself. One way or another, by using this method you almost certainly avoid OOM problem

Comment: got it, I saw the solution and I think for the first answer the second solution is more efficient, how can I read the excel file from a directory and I need to exclude the file which has 'A001' in the file name? I am unable to make the changes could you please help

Comment: @Zeren so...
If you want to read it from directory use this guide - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-all-excel-files-under-a-directory-as-a-pandas-dataframe/

Or you can specify some file, for example " pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0) " (of course, instead of tmp use other file)

Comment: @Zeren If it is needed, i can duplicate my comment as an another answer

About A001

import pandas as pd
import glob

# getting excels from Dir
path = "C:\Users\some_user\Desktop\" #or use here your path

filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
print('File names:', filenames) # just to make sure that every file will be included

# loop over all excel files 
for file in filenames:
   # reading excel files
   if ("A001" not in file):
       print("Reading file = ",file)
       print(pd.read_excel(file))
   else:
       print(f"This file has A001 in name ", {file})