# How to read all excel files under a directory as a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple of excel sheets (using `pd.read_excel` ) under a directory and would like to read them as a pandas and add them to a list. so my list should end up having multiple dataframe in it. How can I do that?

Comment: What code do you have so far?  You could just get your current directory, look for excel file, read them to df, put them in list.

Comment: 1. Please follow the guide for good questions -> where is your code what have you tried so far what error did you encounter

Comment: 2. then we might help you better.    3, take a look into `pathlib` and `Path` and it's `glob` method and how `list comprehension` works

Comment: Try this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

My method for this:

```
 data = os.listdir('data')
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in data:
       path = 'data' + '/' + file
       temp = pd.read_excel(path)
       df = df.append(temp, ignore_index = True)
```