# How read excel from folder without specify excel name?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, path

I want to read_excel from folder and load into database, but the excel will refresh every week and change name (ReportWK01, ReportWK02,...) In that folder (names To_Load) is only the one excel I need.

I tried specify path and then read_excel, but I don't know the correct syntax.

```
path = rb'\\csd-file\dd\bb\ss\uu\To_Load'
results = os.path.join(path, rb"*\*.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(results, engine='python')
```

It's write me

```
ValueError: Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io.
```

Comment: Do you really need that engine parameter `engine='python'` ?

Comment: may be this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat, also chheck the `glob` func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## can you try reading it based on most recent time stamp
import os                                                                   
import glob             

folder_path ='\\csd-file\dd\bb\ss\uu\To_Load'

# glob.glob returns all paths matching the pattern.
excel_files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.xls*')))

mod_dates = [os.path.getmtime(f) for f in excel_files]
print(mod_dates)
# sort by mod_dates.
file_date = sorted(zip(excel_files, mod_dates),reverse=True)
print("*"*100)
print(file_date)
newest_file_path = file_date[0][0]
df = pd.read_excel(newest_file_path)
```

Comment: vrana95 It writes me TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components

Comment: Can you just try to give the exact folder path in folder_path . i have update code

Comment: 'zip' object has no attribute 'sort' So i tried `file_date = zip(excel_files, mod_dates)         
file_date=sorted(file_date, key=lambda d: d[1])` And it writes me IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I only added r before path and `excel_files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, r'*.xls*')))` and it works. Thank you :)