# Python: How to loop through multiple sheets from one excel file and combine them into one dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have one excel file that has multiple sheets that share some columns and rows (all numeric data). I found this good question but that not really answer my question, [Import multiple excel sheets from different files into python and concatenate them into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584591/import-multiple-excel-sheets-from-different-files-into-python-and-concatenate-th)

I am looking for a way to loop through all the sheets located in one single excel file and combine them into one table by summing the shared columns and rows.

For example, one sheet:

```
  Subject   Modifier    Tech_A   Chart_A  Unknown_B  Tech_B
    A         Tech_A      1        4         1         2
    A         Chart_A     3        3         2         4
    B         Unknown_B   4        2         4         5
    B         Tech_B      5        1         3         3
```

Another sheet,

```
  Subject   Modifier    Tech_A  Chart_A  Unknown_A Unknown_B  Tech_B  Chart_B
    A         Tech_A      1        4         1         2        1       1
    A         Chart_A     3        3         2         4        3       2
    A         Unknown_A   1        2         5         3        3       4
    B         Unknown_B   4        2         4         5        5       3
    B         Tech_B      5        1         3         3        2       5
    B         Chart_B     1        1         2         4        2       0
```

The combined single file will merge all the data and sum the similar ones,

```
  Subject   Modifier    Tech_A  Chart_A  Unknown_A Unknown_B  Tech_B  Chart_B
    A         Tech_A      2        8         1         3        3       1
    A         Chart_A     6        6         2         6        7       2
    A         Unknown_A   1        2         5         3        3       4
    B         Unknown_B   8        4         4         9        10      3
    B         Tech_B      10       2         3         6        6       5
    B         Chart_B     1        1         2         4        2       0
```

How can I achieve this in python?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('2018_Sales_Total.xlsx', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
df = df.groupby('Modifier').sum()
```

According to the documentation, specifing [sheet_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to 'None' you get all sheets.

Comment: This will put everything together. The data is huge and this will put everything there. Is there a way to loop through the sheets and sum while adding them?

Comment: i've edited my answer. By executing ```groupby``` and summarizing the values you should get to what you desire.

Comment: This calculated the sum. But for somehow I got duplicate columns and those duplicate has different values. Thank you for help!